# org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in [...] entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I set up a very basic Grails 3 web-app connected to a PostgreSQL db using jdbc. Below you can find code for `Cluster` domain class and the dedicated service.

It happened to call the `createCluster` method twice with the same `slug` argument:

```
clusterService.createCluster('Cluster 1', 'cl01')
clusterService.createCluster('Cluster 2', 'cl01')
```

resulting in the following exception

```
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_9ig73x9wropf95ogrffcvyahk"
  Detail: Key (slug)=(cl01) already exists.
[...]
null id in myPackage.Cluster entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs). Stacktrace follows:
    org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in myPackage.Cluster entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93) ~[grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.usablenet.utest.AdminController.clusters(AdminController.groovy:28) ~[main/:na]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53) ~[spring-security-core-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62) ~[spring-security-core-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58) ~[spring-security-core-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_60-ea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60-ea]
```

I assumed that the violation of the `unique` constraint would had been intercepted by the `.validate()` method, but apparently I was wrong. Ok, so I added a try/catch but it basically has no effect, the exception is not wrapped and I basically get a 500 Internal Error.

My questions are 2:

1. why isn't this exception catched as i would expect?
2. what does `null id / don't flush the Session after an exception occurs` error really mean? I'm not explicitly flushing the session, and of course the new record's id is null...

After checking a few threads pointing out the same issue, 2 of them hinted to set `JTA` to `TRUE` for the data source that Hibernate is using.
Said that I have no clue how to do that, as far as I understood JTA is more oriented to manage multiple transactions among multiple databases, so I'd definitely say it's not my case... Am I right?

**Cluster.groovy** (domain class)

```
class Cluster {

    String name
    String slug

    static constraints = {
        name    blank: false, unique: true
        slug    blank: false, unique: true
    }

}
```

**ClusterService.groovy**

```
@Transactional
class ClusterService {

    public Cluster createCluster(String name, String slug, boolean flush = false) {
        Cluster cluster = new Cluster(name: name, slug: slug)
        try {
            if(cluster.validate())
                cluster.save(flush: flush)
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return cluster
    }
}
```

**application.yml** (db configuration)

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    driverClassName: 'org.postgresql.Driver'
    dialect: 'org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect'
    username: 'postgres'
    password: 'postgres'

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create
            url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp
```

Comment: I know there are a few other similar questions, but unfortunately I really feel they don't fit my case..

Comment: Error is not caught because you catch exception and Hibernate is doing assert, try catching `Throwable` instead. `Don't flush the session` means exactly what is written - hibernate session should not be flushed after error like the one you get - or invalid object should be discarded before session flush. Grails will automatically flush the session in certain points. This error should not occur if unique is working fine. As for unique, you are right, it should be caught. Which version of Grails are you on? Where do you execute `clusterService.createCluster()` methods? can you show that code?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @droggo!
`Throwable` didn't add any detail unfortunately, the stacktrace looks the same as before.

Comment: I'm using Grails 3.1.1. The calls to `createCluster` were performed in `Boostrap.groovy`, but moving the calls to a controller, e.g. `clusterService.createCluster(params.name, params.slug)` gives the same results.
One more thing I noticed is that making `clusterService` non transactional at least I don't get 500 status anymore, but stacktrace and exception are the same, including `true` as 'unexpected' outcome by `.validate()` method with duplicated `slug`.

Comment: If you can make small project on Github which reproduces that I could help more, otherwise it's hard to tell what is wrong

Comment: I found out the solution while creating a Github demo ([here](https://github.com/ilPittiz/unique) it is however) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While building a demo from scratch, I found out that the issue is not my code, rather in the Grails app's configuration (`build.gradle`), as merely changing the dependency

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
```

to

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
```

made the problem disappear, with `.validate()` returning `false` as expected and no Error being thrown.

However I couldn't find any note about incompatibilities between Grails 3 
and Hibernate 3, it would had been nice to find one :P